How Do I Make This Graph Cleanly From Saturday to Sunday Without the Half Bars?
I am trying to create a bar graph to represent data over a week. Everything seems fine but the first and last bars (for Saturday) appear to be cut in half. My code is below. How can I fix this?

nf = px.bar(dmt, x='date', y='Nutrition', title="Nutrition Scores", width=0.5)
nf.update_xaxes({'range': ('2024-06-08', '2024-06-15')}, tickmode='linear', 
tickformat='%a <br> %d', title=None)
nf.update_yaxes(title='Nutrition')
nf.update_layout(title_x=0.5, plot_bgcolor="white", paper_bgcolor="white")
nf.update_traces(marker_color='#1e439d')


maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run. And add example data directly in code.

I believe that when you set the range using dates, the time of day defaults to 00:00 which leads to the bars being cut off because the are all centered at 00:00. One workaround would be to pad the range with 12 hours. For example:
nf.update_xaxes({'range': ('2024-06-07 12:00:00', '2024-06-15 12:00:00')}, tickmode='linear', 
tickformat='%a <br> %d', title=None)


